# How to get the maximum out of a list of "hh:mm" timestamps?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, max

I have a list of time strings (music tracks lengths) just like this:

```py
music_lengths = ['4:30', '4:59', '7:30', ...]
```

How can I find the maximum value (longest track) of that list?

Comment: To whoever voted to close as "needs more focus", you should probably read the explanatory text for that reason. It's meant to handle questions that are a lot of different questions in one. I don't think it applies in this case, unless you consider removing the colon and finding the maximum to be wildly disparate questions, which I'd personally find rather hard to justify :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo, I would rather vote for dup.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could convert to `time` objects using [`time.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html?highlight=strptime#time.strptime) and take the max based on those values:

```py
import time

music_lengths = ['4:30', '11:04', '4:59', '7:30', '1:23']
longest = max(music_lengths, key=lambda t:time.strptime(t, '%M:%S'))
print(longest)
```

Output (for my sample data)

```
11:04
```

Comment: The fornat spec should be `'%M:%S'` to treat the first part of the duration string as minutes, not months. Otherwise a duration >= `13:00` will fail.

Comment: @mhawke thanks for pointing that out, my finger must have slipped off the shift key for the `m` and since I didn't go far enough with my durations I didn't notice. I've corrected.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could try with pandas as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
if __name__ == '__main__':
    music_lengths = ["4:30", "4:59", "7:30", "3:25"]
    df = pd.DataFrame(music_lengths, columns=["length"])
    df["length"]= pd.to_datetime(df["length"], format="%H:%M").dt.time
    print(df.max())
```

The code converts a string column to a datetime column and outputs only the time part. I used the format "%H:%M" since the problem states the format of "hh:mm".

Result:

```
07:30:00
```

Answer (score 2):

This might be a bit lengthy but just for sake of variety:

```
>>> music_lengths = ['4:30', '4:59', '7:30', '11:40', '0:30', '22:45', 
'7:31', '12:40']
>>> 
 >>> sorted(music_lengths, key=lambda x: list(map(int, x.split(':'))))[-1]
'22:45'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can plainly use `sorted()` for that like this (minutes-only):

```
>>> music_lengths = ['4:30', '4:59', '7:30', '0:01']
>>> sorted(music_lengths, key=lambda item: int(item.split(':')[0]))
['0:01', '4:30', '4:59', '7:30']
```

For more precise approach with minutes and seconds `time` module should be used as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66111140/5994041) or calculating it manually to seconds:

```
>>> sorted(music_lengths, key=lambda item: int(item.split(':')[0]) * 60 + int(item.split(':')[1]))
['0:01', '4:30', '4:59', '7:30']
```

Comment: The first suggestion is wrong. It just sorts on the minutes. What if `music_lengths` is `['4:59', '4:30', '7:30', '0:01']`? 4:59 will sort before 4:30. The second suggestion loses the string format of the input - you'd need to covert it back.

Answer (score -1):

```
x = [int(element.replace(':','')) for element in music_lengths]
max(x)
```

Comment: This will sort `11:04` as being less than `7:30`

Comment: Note this will note return original value

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.